# LotusScript and CSV import and string manipulation

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I am importing CSV file into Lotus notes ( Notes client application ), and have to check if incoming field is date or not.

The incoming string would look like below :

```
{ CriteriaDate= 5/12/2007, testing | Incoming= 5/12/2018,test| outgoing = test1,test2 }
```

Here it is not confirm that the first value after = would be always be the date it can be string, but I want to make sure if that is date then it should create date field into the lotus notes document.

Like from above there would be field which needs to be created as below:

```
CriteriaDate = 5/12/2007
CriteriaText ="testiing"
IncomingDate=5/12/2018
IncomingText ="test"
OutgoingText ="test1", "test2"
```

The specification observation here I want to make is that if first crietria after "=" sign is date or not using lotusscript.

please help.

Comment: Show us the code that you have tried.  Are you aware of the Split() function?

Answer (score 0):

Use LotusScript's [IsDate()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/LSAZ_ISDATE_FUNCTION.html) function.

For example `IsDate("5/12/2007")`returns true and  `IsDate("what is this")` returns false.

Comment: This does not work at all, as it does not returns true for isdate("5/12/2007")

Comment: It depends on your server or client data format settings (e.g. US, UK, DE...)

Comment: Means, could you please help me what could be done in this case I dont want any workstation related dependency, I have incoming string which is date like "5/12/2017", now what I want to do is I want to check if this is date or not ? I implemented below as but it did not work, I am using Notes 9. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21304700

Comment: OK, then you have to test date format on your own. First look, if string contains "/" and if yes, then check for valid values day/month/year. Use LotusScript functions InStr() and Split() or StrToken().